# Pipe emails from Postfix to script using virtual-alias-maps

Tags: postfix-mta

I’m using Postfix/Dovecot and I’m trying to pipe incoming messages that are received to my ‘catch-all’ account to a script, while ignoring messages that are received to pre-defined user mailboxes.

I’ve been successful at getting the script to run if I specify my domain name within the ‘mydestination’ variable inside the main.cf file, but according to the postfix documentation, every hostname listed in  ‘mydestination’ is considered LOCAL by Postfix and thus it tries to deliver mail to that local user – which in my case doesn’t exist because I’m using VIRTUAL users as configured in virtual-alias-maps.

I've spent hours surfing various threads here on SO and other forums, but I'm coming up empty.  I need a way to send only the messages received to this catch-all account to a script.  Does anyone have any experience sending a script to only specific users in such a manner and could maybe offer a suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more what you are trying to do ? 
You want Postfix to catch all the incoming mails to a directory, and then you want to run a script which will do some treatments to these mails ?

In this case, you have to configure Postfix (main.cf).
Then you have to make your script run on the right directory. 
I don't think you need to make Postfix and the script communicate.

If you need more help in Postfix configuration to catch all the incoming mails in one directory, let me know, I can help.